# How to insert/update data in custom table using Magento 2 using Ajax but 404 error occur on ajax hit?

Tags: magento2, admin, ajax, 404, data

I have created a custom module for admin area in which i have show some data in phtml file.
I have created a custom table in database using installschema.php.

Now i want to save that data in database but on hitting the update button ajax url is hit but the response it gives me 404.

My file path are

My URL is http://127.0.0.1/magento/AdminSample/datasave/index/?isAjax=true

My controller file path is ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/Controller/Adminhtml/Datasave/Index.php )

```
<?php
namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Controller\Adminhtml\Datasave;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface; // Needed to retrieve config values

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
 protected $resultPageFactory;
/**
 * @var scopeConfig
 * Needed to retrieve config values
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig // Needed to retrieve config values
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig; // Needed to retrieve config values
}

/**
* Index Action*
* @return void
*/
public function execute()
{
    /*$post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    var_dump($post);*/
    die('a');
}
}
```

My JS file path is ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/view/adminhtml/web/js/adminscript.js )

My routes.xml file path ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml )

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="AdminSample" frontName="AdminSample">
        <module name="Tym17_AdminSample" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

My JS file is ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/view/adminhtml/web/js/adminscript.js )

```
require(["jquery","mage/url"],function($,url) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('123');
    url.setBaseUrl(BASE_URL);
    var BaseUrl = url.build('');
    jQuery( ".product" ).on( 'click', '.save',function() {
        console.log('click');
        let customurl = "http://127.0.0.1/magento/AdminSample/Datasave/index/";
        let dataid = jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('.dataid').text();
        $.ajax({
            url: customurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                dataid:dataid
            },
            complete: function(response) {             
                console.log('aaaaa');
            },
        });
    });
});
});
```

My controller file path ( app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Index.php )

```
<?php
namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
protected $resultPageFactory = false;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

public function execute()
{
    echo'controller check'; die('aaahahahah123');
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Posts')));

    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

if anything else needed i will add that any help is appreciated.

Comment: First open this link in new tab - http://127.0.0.1/magento/AdminSample/Datasave/index & check if you see anything or it gets to 404.

Comment: Visit http://127.0.0.1/magento/AdminSample/Datasave in your browser & check.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/reg-dealers/AdminSample/datasave/index and http://127.0.0.1/reg-dealers/AdminSample/Datasave/index this link goes to 404 and Datasave or datasave means D is in small letter both link goes to 404 will you please help @HamendraSunthwal

Comment: I have added answer modify file as per answer i posted to this question & check.

Answer (score 0):

Modify files as per below answer & then use the controller url in ajax url.

Step 1- app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
<route id="adminsample" frontName="adminsample">
            <module name="Tym17_AdminSample"/>
        </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

Step 2: Create controller file
File: app/code/Tym17/AdminSample/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Index.php

```
   <?php
    namespace Tym17\AdminSample\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;
    
    class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo'controller check'; exit;
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Posts')));

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Step 3 - Check controller

Browse this link  `127.0.0.1/magento/adminsample/post/index`

Comment: run di:compile & clear cache after file modification

Comment: Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes it works and shows the result but a question if i want to run ajax on admin side then these files are not in adminhtml folder these are work on admin side as well ?@Hamendra

Comment: Let me update answer

Comment: Answer updated now it will work for adminhtml, just move your controller code into this controller & change folder name as per your requirement.

Comment: It that works for you upvote answer & mark as right, it will be helpful for magento community.

Comment: I have created conroller file with same name Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Index.php on hitting that url in browser or in ajax js it goes to 404 @Hamendra

Comment: Please have a look here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320923/magento-2-redirect-custom-attribute-option-to-cms-page-url-in-obsever

Comment: Updated my controller file path with code as you suggested please check @HamendraSunthwal

Comment: <route id="AdminSample" frontName="AdminSample">
should be  <route id="adminsample" frontName="adminsample">

Comment: Mark answer as right if it helped you, later it can help community too.