# Magento 2: Redirect custom attribute option to cms page url in obsever

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, collection

How to redirect if custom attribute option value != 5431 to cms page else redirect to module Controller (prescription/index).

Till now both conditions redirecting to  module Controller

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_order = $order;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
                        
        $orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
        
        foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $_item){        
        $product = $_item->getProductId();          
        //echo $_item->getName(); die();
        
        $is_priscription =  $_item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute('prescription');         
        
        if($is_priscription != '5431'){
            $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('order-success');
            return $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
            }
        }       
        
        $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        
        if ($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which observer you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here use if else condition it first match all the conditions then proceed further

```
<?php

namespace Softadroit\Prescription\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Orderplaceafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
        $this->_order = $order;
    }
    
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {       
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $_checkoutSession = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        $_quoteFactory = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
                        
        $orderid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
        
        $order = $_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
        $quote = $_quoteFactory->create()->loadByIdWithoutStore($order->getQuoteId());
        
        foreach($order->getItemsCollection() as $_item){        
        $product = $_item->getProductId();          
        //echo $_item->getName(); die();
        
        $is_priscription = $_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('prescription'); 
        //echo $_item->getProduct()->getPrescription();
        //exit;
        
        if($is_priscription == '' && $is_priscription != '5431'){
             $redirectionUrl =  $this->_url->getUrl('order-success');
             $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
             return $this;
              //return;
              exit;
            }               
        
        else if($is_priscription == '' && $is_priscription != '5431' && ($quote->getId())){
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
            
        } else if($quote->getId()) {
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $_checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->_url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
            die();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirection from observer specailly `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` is not right way.

Instead of using **observer**, use  **Around Plugin** on `\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success::execute` is best.

Create `di.xml` at `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/etc/frontend/`

**Add below code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="VendorName_ModuleName_Plugin_Frontend_Magento_Checkout_Controller_Onepage_Success" sortOrder="10" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create plugin class  `Success.php` at `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Plugin/Frontend/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/`

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class Success
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    private $objectManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    private $redirectFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    private $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;
    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $cartRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory
     */
    private $quoteFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        OrderRepositoryInterface  $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        UrlInterface  $url
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage\Success $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $session = $this->checkoutSession;
        if (!$this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
        $orderId = $session->getLastOrderId();
        $order  = $this->getOrder((int) $orderId);

        if (empty($orderId) ||!$order) {
            return $proceed();
        }


        $match = false;

        foreach ($order->getItemsCollection() as $_item) {
            $product = $_item->getProductId();
            $is_priscription =  $_item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute('prescription');
            if ($is_priscription != '5431') {
                $match = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($match) {
            /***
             * Clear Session if require
             */
            //$this->checkoutSession->clearQuote();

            $customRedirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('order-success');
            return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setUrl($customRedirectionUrl);
        }

        $quote = $this->getQuote((int)$order->getQuoteId());
        if ($quote && $quote->getId()) {
            /***
             * Clear Session if require
             */
            //$this->checkoutSession->clearQuote();
            $quote->setIsActive(1)->setReservedOrderId(null)->save();
            $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
            $url = $this->url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setUrl($url);
        }
        return $proceed();
    }
    private function getOrder($orderId)
    {
        try {
            return $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function getQuote($quoteId)
    {
        try {
            return  $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it not return for both conditions can you please recheck the updated code

Comment: Now it redirect both the to order-success

Comment: have u checked that `if ($match) {` is executed?

Comment: Yes its executed but both 5431 anda !5431 redirected to success page

Comment: okay,  have u understand what is mean of `if ($is_priscription != '5431') {
                $match = true;
                break;
            }`

Comment: if any  item of an order does not have `is_priscription` value `5431` then  it will redirect to `order-success`  Url

Comment: Yes I understand But ```if ($is_priscription == '5431')``` then it should be redirect to   ```$url = $this->url->getUrl('prescription/index'); //('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setUrl($url);```

Comment: Any Response..?

Comment: yes, if `if ($is_priscription == '5431')`  will  match then `return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setUrl($url);` should redirect

Comment: But this code is not working for that

Comment: ```$is_priscription =  $_item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute('prescription'); ```
This didnot echo any value I think here is the problem, can you please check this